# moving handle of unity3d slider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uislider

I am working on a `unity3d 4.7.0f1` project and want handle of slider to move left-right from `min` value to `max` value and back until I click on button.

What is the best way?

Comment: Do you mean slowly ping-pong loop between min-max? Its the new UI default Slider component?

Comment: Yes, like a Ping-Pong. And yes, its the UI Slider. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's sample script for setting slider value between 0-max (Mathf.PingPong expects min value to be 0). You can check assign button click to disable this script (so Update loop stops running)

Attach to empty gameobject, assign Slider to it, test.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SliderPingPong : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider slider;
    public float speed = 1;
    float pos = 0;

    void Update()
    {
        pos += speed * Time.deltaTime;
        slider.value = Mathf.PingPong(pos, slider.maxValue);
    }
}
```

same script source in gist:
https://gist.github.com/unitycoder/a69c4ff5324336cfa33bde23c09d7397

Answer (score 2):

`slider.SetValueWithoutNotify` can be used to avoid triggering the value-update callback.